# Getting NPE while setting headers in post request

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, rest-assured

I'm trying to draft a post request and while doing so it is giving NPE. I'm using rest assured and cucumber.

PFB code from SalesCRM.java:

```
HashMap <String, String> headers;

JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
BigInteger endPlacementTimestamp = new BigInteger("1593611640000");
BigInteger startPlacementTimestamp = new BigInteger("1594216440000");
payload.put("endPlacementTimestamp",endPlacementTimestamp );
payload.put("startPlacementTimestamp",startPlacementTimestamp);
headers.put("authorization","Bearer cd70f469-b963-48f1-9486-fe5d5e3c443b");//line76
response = (Response) AuxiliarMethods.postRequest(url,values,headers,"application/json",payload.toJSONString());
```

Stack trace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at locustTask.SalesCRM.execute(SalesCRM.java:76)
>
> at com.github.myzhan.locust4j.AbstractTask.run(AbstractTask.java:63)
>
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in that code.

As you can see here: `at locustTask.SalesCRM.execute(SalesCRM.java:76)`

It means that the NPE is happening in class **SalesCRM** line **76**.

UPDATE

Now it is more clear, thank you.

Your problem is because your are trying to call the method ‘.put’ for a object that was not initialized.

Your object “headers” is null.

To fix it just initialize the object.

`HashMap <String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: in the code snippet, I have pasted here from that class only and at line 76             headers.put("authorization","Bearer cd70f469-b963-48f1-9486-fe5d5e3c443b"); is set. Have updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: i have done some changes and now I'm getting                                                                Jul 09, 2020 7:40:33 PM helpers.AuxiliarMethods postRequest
INFO: Exception occurred: parametersMap cannot be null
JsonResponse:  null